# Help with erratic mouse behaviour

Tags: unity, mouse, mouse-scroll

on the verge of destroying my PC and living in the woods right now... I run a dual boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Recently my mouse has started to do weird things:

- When I hover over the volume icon, the volume increases itself
- When I hover over a drop down menu it scrolls to the bottom option
- If I hover over the icon of an active application on the sidebar, it brings it to the front, without clicking.

I tried the mouse with another computer and it works fine. I've also tried a different mouse with the computer and the same happens. The problem also existed in Windows but stopped when I disabled the HID compliant mouse driver. I'm pretty sure I haven't changed anything in Ubuntu so I'm not sure why it's doing this all of a sudden.

(Already tried a clean install)

Any suggestions would receive lots of gratefulness,
Thanks

EDIT- This doesn't affect actual windows, they don't scroll unnaturally at all

Comment: This sounds like a mouse hardware issue... what mouse is it? Looks like it's scrolling without you actually scrolling.

Comment: It's a microsoft wireless mouse 3000, It seems to work perfectly fine on other machines though. I tried placing the pointer on the volume icon and then unplugging the adapter and it carried on scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Of all things... it was the wireless keyboard interfering with mouse.... Unplugged the adapter and plugged it back in --> success

Devastated it was that simple after reinstalling the OS...